# How to display a welcome message in php

Tags: php

I have these two buttons.

```
  <div class="buttons">         
       <a class="button exc-tax" href="http://siteking-test.tk/taxswitcher/?price_display=1&amp;redirect=aHR0cDovL3NpdGVraW5nLXRlc3QudGsv">Excl. VAT</a>                 
       <a class="button inc-tax" href="http://siteking-test.tk/taxswitcher/?price_display=2&amp;redirect=aHR0cDovL3NpdGVraW5nLXRlc3QudGsv">Incl. VAT</a>     
  </div>
```

When pressed, they change the price display of my website products.

All I need is a display message at the top of the page to say which button was last pressed. For example, if I pressed the excluding VAT button. It would go to the link and display all products with prices excluding tax. This part is already working. All I am looking for now is a message at the top of the page to say if we are viewing the prices with tax or without tax (obviously depending on what was just pressed)

The logic behind it would be, button 1 was last pressed so display button 1 message

OR

Button 2 was just pressed so display button 2 message

Comment: <div class="buttons">         <a class="button exc-tax"           href="http://siteking-test.tk/taxswitcher/?price_display=1&amp;redirect=aHR0cDovL3NpdGVraW5nLXRlc3QudGsv">Excl. VAT</a>          <a class="button inc-tax" href="http://siteking-test.tk/taxswitcher/?price_display=2&amp;redirect=aHR0cDovL3NpdGVraW5nLXRlc3QudGsv">Incl. VAT</a>     </div>

Comment: You're asking for debug/coding help, but didn't provide enough code nor information about your problem, neither made an [Minimum, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of it to be reproduced. Please, revise your question.

Comment: Forget the code, I knew that would confuse things. What I am after seems really basic. I have two URLs that change the website so they display different prices when clicked. I just want to display a message to say which URL had been clicked. I want to know if there is a way to set an ID when the button is clicked so that I can display a message in php depending on the button

Comment: The logic behind it is

If button 1 was last pressed, then say this message
If button 2 was last pressed, then display this message instead

Comment: *Is there possibly a way to set an ID when a URL is clicked and then have a IF statement saying, if the id is 1 display this message, if the id is 2 display this message* -- yes there is, pass it as URL parameter (`foo.php?id=1`) and use `$_GET` superglobal to retrieve it.

Comment: It seems you can actually do it with the params you already have, `price_display` differs from 1 to 2, test for it.

Comment: The URL doesnt change though, it redirects to the home page but just remembers that the price structure has changed so updates on every page.

Comment: <?php  
        if($price_display=2){
        ?>
        <p>You are now viewing prices INC TAX. </p>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php  
        if($price_display=1){
        ?>
        <p>You are now viewing prices EX TAX. </p>
        <?php } ?>

Comment: That just displays both...

Comment: Because your `if` is wrong! It has to be `if($_GET['price_display'] == 1) { // message when its one } elseif ($_GET['price_display'] == 2) { // message when it's two, with elseif just to be sure it's not other number}`

Comment: http://siteking-test.tk/

Go on the website and check the top right hand corner. You will see what I mean

Comment: You know, now that you showed this, it's more clear that your php code is relevant. The `if` statement you commented here just reassigns values to $price_display again, thus evaluating to true **every time**. That's probably why your code is showing everything together.

Comment: And consider this, you tagged the post `php` but there is not php code to be analyzed . Please, post at least the part where it receives and evaluates the url parameter to write the sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this. Answer is available in your question too. You have one parameter in common for both buttons i.e. price_display. You just simply put the following code into your php file.

```
 <?php
    if(isset($_GET['price_display']) && $_GET['price_display']>1){
     echo "currently viewing the website including tax.";
    }else{
     echo "currently viewing the website excluding tax.";
    }
 ?>
```

Above code should be added at the top of your php file (if you are willing to display message on top).